# How to create moss or grass in the cracks of bricks

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I want to solve this problem, I don't know how to create this landscape. I hope there is a nice person who can answer my doubts

Comment: Hello, maybe tell a bit more, do you plan to use mage textures? procedural? particles? what are you struggling with exactly? etc...

Comment: Hi nuo xu, since you are new here...this forum has some very strict rules and one is: you are allowed only to ask for one specific problem, you mustn't ask for tutorials or "broad" problems. So either you improve your question and just ask for a specific detail ...or you go e.g. to blenderartists.org and ask there the same question - no problem to ask there.

Comment: Thank you guys I will improve my questions

Answer (score 0):

Create a mix between a pavement texture (*Image Texture* 2) and a grass texture (*Image Texture* 3), plug a black image (*Image Texture* 1) into the factor of the *Mix Shader*:

[image]

Select the *Image Texture* 1 and switch to *Texture Paint* mode and use a white color to reveal the second texture:

[image]